# Make a generic "Can I activate my retail CD key of [GAME] on Steam?"

Tags: discussion

Steam has this lovely Knowledge Base article that lists the CD-Keys they accept from retail copies: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601

I suggest that we make a generic question for these types of questions and just mark others as duplicates.  [We](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/136669/42984) [have](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/45331/42984) [quite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/26016/42984) [a](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/73702/42984) [few](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/34866/42984).

Answer (score 1):

Just ask and self-answer the question, so that it's there for next time.

If it's considered useful, people will start VTC as duplicate to it and eventually maybe those ones you found will be marked as duplicates of it too. (Remember that things don't have to be instant around here, so you can let our future selves and their voting habits take care of marking as duplicate.)

If it's not considered useful, no harm no foul and it might just help someone incoming from Google.

So, go make the question and answer it with a nice presentation of that Knowledge Base link. We don't need a meta to decide this.